# Jquery: How to detect "tab from" vs "shift-tab from" an object

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

```html
<ul>
  <li id="item1">item1</li>
  <li id="item2">item2</li>
  <li id="item3">item3</li>
 </ul>
```

Concider the code snippet above as a part of a menu on a web page. 
I'd like to tab and also shift-tab trough the items in the code snippet above.

- When I tab out of the last item, focus shall be set on the first item.
- When I <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the first item, focus shall be set on the
  last item

I shall never be able to leave the list while using the keyboard.

Is this possible using Jquery? 
If so, how could I write the code?

`.focusout()` won't help since (as far as I know) it can not detect the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> event.

**Update**: A suitable answer is found here: [jQuery tab and shift+tab to show navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657589/jquery-tab-and-shifttab-to-show-navigation)

Comment: Something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657589/jquery-tab-and-shifttab-to-show-navigation

Comment: Thanks a lot @SahilDhir that was exactly what I was looking for. Updating my question with a link to that other question.

Comment: You are welcome :)